# Convert arraylist elements order in sequence based on day

Tags: java, java-6

Below is the output from database. These sequence orders can not be the same every time. Here the days are not in sequence order . I need these days in sequence order.

```
ArrayList dayList= [ MONDAY   : 9:00AM - 5:00PM , TUESDAY  : 9:00AM - 5:00PM , WEDNESDAY: 9:00AM - 5:00PM , FRIDAY   : 9:00AM - 5:00PM,  THURSDAY : 9:00AM - 5:00PM , SATURDAY : C L O S E D  , SUNDAY   : C L O S E D , APPOINTMENT REQUIREMENT]
```

I need to convert the output in  sequence order like the below:

```
[ MONDAY   : 9:00AM - 5:00PM , TUESDAY  : 9:00AM - 5:00PM , WEDNESDAY: 9:00AM - 5:00PM , THURSDAY : 9:00AM - 5:00PM , FRIDAY   : 9:00AM - 5:00PM,  SATURDAY : C L O S E D  , SUNDAY   : C L O S E D , APPOINTMENT REQUIREMENT]
```

Comment: `dayList` looks like `String` representation of the `List`. Could you provide how it looks like using objects? What kind of types do you have? Also, much better is ordering these items on `DB` side.

Comment: Are the values in the array strings?

Comment: @preciousbetine:- Yes, all are Strings in Arraylist.

Comment: The you need to parse those strings first, so you know the day. What have you tried?

Comment: It's probably down-voted because there is *literally* NO attempt from OP to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work. It uses regex to extract the day name, and [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) from the Java 8 Time API to get the day number from the day name.

```
List<String> dayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        "SATURDAY : C L O S E D",
        "TUESDAY  : 9:00AM - 5:00PM",
        "FRIDAY   : 9:00AM - 5:00PM",
        "MONDAY   : 9:00AM - 5:00PM",
        "SUNDAY   : C L O S E D",
        "WEDNESDAY: 9:00AM - 5:00PM",
        "APPOINTMENT REQUIREMENT",
        "THURSDAY : 9:00AM - 5:00PM"));

// Sort list by day name
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+DAY)\\s*:");
dayList.sort(Comparator.<String>comparingInt(s -> {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    return (m.find() ? DayOfWeek.valueOf(m.group(1)).getValue() : 8);
}));

// Print the sorted list
dayList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output*

```
MONDAY   : 9:00AM - 5:00PM
TUESDAY  : 9:00AM - 5:00PM
WEDNESDAY: 9:00AM - 5:00PM
THURSDAY : 9:00AM - 5:00PM
FRIDAY   : 9:00AM - 5:00PM
SATURDAY : C L O S E D
SUNDAY   : C L O S E D
APPOINTMENT REQUIREMENT
```

---

**UPDATE** Java 5+ solution, same output as above:

```
final class DayComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    private final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
            "^(?:(MON)|(TUES)|(WEDNES)|(THURS)|(FRI)|(SATUR)|(SUN))DAY\\s*:");
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return dayValue(s1) - dayValue(s2);
    }
    private int dayValue(String s) {
        Matcher m = this.p.matcher(s);
        if (m.find())
            for (int i = 1; ; i++)
                if (m.start(i) != -1)
                    return i;
        return 8;
    }
}
```

```
List<String> dayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(
        "SATURDAY : C L O S E D",
        "TUESDAY  : 9:00AM - 5:00PM",
        "FRIDAY   : 9:00AM - 5:00PM",
        "MONDAY   : 9:00AM - 5:00PM",
        "SUNDAY   : C L O S E D",
        "WEDNESDAY: 9:00AM - 5:00PM",
        "APPOINTMENT REQUIREMENT",
        "THURSDAY : 9:00AM - 5:00PM"));

// Sort list by day name
Collections.sort(dayList, new DayComparator());

// Print the sorted list
for (String s : dayList)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Great answer, I can't come up with better but the tag says java-6, perhaps edit?

Comment: This won't work in java 6

Comment: For Java 6 & 7, most of the *java.time* functionality is available in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project.

Comment: Thank you. But any sample code which works for Java 6 ?

Comment: @Ravikanth *Huh?!?* I just added code which works for Java 5+ (which means for Java 5 and any later version, which includes Java 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, ...).

Answer (score 0):

This won't work in Java 6 but the concept holds and is easy enough to translate:

Java 8 streams alternative:

```
private static final List<String> DATES =
        List.of("MONDAY   : 9:00AM - 5:00PM",
                "TUESDAY  : 9:00AM - 5:00PM",
                "WEDNESDAY: 9:00AM - 5:00PM",
                "FRIDAY   : 9:00AM - 5:00PM",
                "THURSDAY : 9:00AM - 5:00PM",
                "SATURDAY : C L O S E D ",
                "SUNDAY   : C L O S E D",
                "APPOINTMENT REQUIREMENT");

private static List<String> getSortedDates() {
    EnumSet<DayOfWeek> dayOfWeeks = EnumSet.allOf(DayOfWeek.class);
    return DATES.stream()
            .map(p -> dayOfWeeks.stream()
                    .filter(q -> p.startsWith(q.name()))
                    .findAny()
                    .map(r -> new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(r.ordinal(), p))
                    .orElse(new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(dayOfWeeks.size(), p)))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(SimpleImmutableEntry::getKey))
            .map(SimpleImmutableEntry::getValue)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    getSortedDates().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Any sample code which works Java 6?